# single sign-on on multiple sites on a same domain

Tags: authentication, cross-platform, single-sign-on, subdomain

my organization wants to be able to create a number of sites, i.e. with different subdomains but on the same domain, i.e. foo.organization.com, bar.organization.com etc. Preferably the users would only have to log in to one site, and then be logged in to the other sites. There might be different server-side platforms used to implement these subdomain sites (some ASP.NET MVC, possibly Django, perhaps Ruby etc.), so this solution should preferably be cross-platform. One of these subdomains will be hosting the API for the main database, and preferably it should support both server-to-server authentication as well as using the API from a client side code.

Any suggestions what route we should go in this?

Regards,
Daníel

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Single Sign On. There are several good solutions out there that would address the need you're describing. You can research SAML, CAS, OpenID and others.

I would personally recommend [RubyCAS](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/) - it's an implementation of [Jasig's CAS protocol](http://www.jasig.org/cas/protocol) in Ruby. I found it easier to set up, though both work just fine.

Any web-based application (and even non-web-based ones) can delegate their authentication to it. It works similarly to how you authenticate to google apps. If you don't have a session open on the particular site you're visiting, you get redirected to the login form on the CAS server and then sent back with a ticket if you're able to authenticate. The ticket is then verified on the back end to ensure it's valid.

There are plenty of CAS clients out there for a variety of platforms. I can personally vouch for [rubycas client](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-client/) and [phpCAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS). Looks like there's [some for Django](https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview), and for legacy apache-served apps, you can use [mod_auth_cas](https://github.com/Jasig/mod_auth_cas), which is basically CASsified HTTP basic auth.

Comment: Sounds promising. Would you happen to know if this would be usable in an application which would basically consist of static HTML pages containing JavaScript code to render the views, and interact with an API to read/write data? I.e. could the users log in to that application, and the login information (i.e. the ticket/access cookie) passed to the API?

Comment: That sounds like an example where you'd want to use the apache module mod_auth_cas. You would protect the subdirectory where your app is located, and if an unauthenticated user attempts to access that directory, he'll get sent to the CAS server login page. It wouldn't require modifying any of your code, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Very Interesting ! I am wondering would that not be the same as what a wamp or lamp server does. I have 44 websites now running on one Lamp-server under the Localhost/each_sites_name/index.php name space. To do subs you would have to create one site_name and place others one level below it.

mainsite
    site1
    site2
    site3
    site4  etc.

Comment: Well, since these sites might be using different frameworks and might therefore be using different web servers, I would prefer a solution which works across different machines.